# How do I turn a string from a csv file into an integer in python?

Tags: python, css, file, csv

I'm writing a code based on this set of information (http://www.databasebasketball.com/players/playerlist.htm) put into a CSV file.

I want to make a code that determines the BMI of each player, then if their BMI is over 30, it will consider them obese.

However, I have to turn the players' height in feet in height in inches, and I'm not sure how to do this without changing the original CSV file.

So far I have:

```
import csv

def read_csv(filename):
    """
    Reads a Comma Separated Value file,
    returns a list of rows; each row is a dictionary of columns.
    """
    with open(filename, encoding="utf_8_sig") as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        rows = list(reader)
    return rows

# Try out the function
players = read_csv("players.csv")

# Print information on the first player, to demonstrate how
# to get to the data
from pprint import pprint
pprint(players[0])
print(players[0]["lastname"])
print(players[0]["weight"])


total_h_inches = print(players[0]["h_feet"*12])
```

but it returns an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\hw5.py", line 24, in <module>
    h_feet = print(players[0]["h_feet"*12])
KeyError: 'h_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feet'
```

I know that I am very far from the end result, but I feel like getting through this step will help a lot.

Comment: The error is self explanatory: There is no key like 'h_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feet' May be you are looking for players[0]['h_feet'] * 12 to convert into inches.

Comment: Please don't change your question after people have answered it - this is confusing for users as the answers already given no longer relate to the question. Instead, ask a new question (once you have spent a little more time researching your new problem.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to cast the string to an Integer using the built in int() functionality...

```
total_h_inches = int(players[0]["h_feet"]) * 12
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory: There is no key like `'h_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feeth_feet'`

in order to convert Feet into inches 
You should use players[0]['h_feet'] * 12 
to convert into inches.

Since `'h_feet' * 12` in the key will change the key name to `h_feeth_feet....upto 12 times`.

Also If the Value in the dictionary is string format, You need to typecast it to integer first like `int(players[0]['h_feet'])` and then multiply by 12

Answer (score 0):

The key misunderstanding, pun intended, is what you expected from

```
"h_feet"*12
```

That evaluates to "h_feet" repeated 12 times.